# How to do snapping in as3 as in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

There are many movieclips placed on stage? Now I want to align them using drag and drop inside movieclips.I want the vertical alignment line appear while placing the selected movieclip under that movieclip as shown in the attached image.

Here is an image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var obj:Rectangle1 = new Rectangle1();
        private var obj1:Rectangle1 = new Rectangle1();
        private var obj2:Rectangle1 = new Rectangle1();
        private var obj3:Rectangle1=new Rectangle1();
        public var Obj_Arr:Array = [];
        private var p:VerticalLine;

        public function Main() 
        {
            obj.x=20;
            obj.y=100;
            addChild(obj);
            obj1.buttonMode = true;
            trace("init()")
            obj.buttonMode=true;
            obj1.x=150;
            obj1.y=100;
            addChild(obj1);

            obj2.buttonMode=true;
            obj2.x=280;
            obj2.y=100;
            addChild(obj2);

            obj3.buttonMode=true;
            obj3.x=430;
            obj3.y=100;
            addChild(obj3);

            p = new VerticalLine();
            addChild(p);
            p.visible = false;

            Obj_Arr.push(obj);
            Obj_Arr.push(obj1);
            Obj_Arr.push(obj2);
            Obj_Arr.push(obj3);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {
                Obj_Arr[i].index = i;
                Obj_Arr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, OnDown);
                Obj_Arr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, OnUp);
            }
        }

        private function OnDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
            trace(e.target.index);
            trace("remove...")
            Obj_Arr.splice(e.target.index,1)
            e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMove);
        }

        private function OnMove(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(e.target.x==(Obj_Arr[i].x)) 
                {
                    p.visible = true;
                    p.x = Obj_Arr[i].x;
                    p.y = Obj_Arr[i].y;
                    i = Obj_Arr.length;
                }
                else
                {
                    p.visible =false;
                }
            }
        }

        private function OnUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            p.visible =false;
            e.target.stopDrag();
            Obj_Arr.push(e.target);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {       
                if(e.target.index == (Obj_Arr[i].index)) 
                {
                    trace("add...");
                    Obj_Arr[i].x = e.target.x;
                    Obj_Arr[i].index = i;
                }
            }
            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMove);
        }
    }   
}
```

But this code isnt working properly.

Please Help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer what all i want,I was doing a mistake that i was setting the array index inside matching condition ,which should be set inside for loop on MOUSE_UP event.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var obj:Rectangle1 = new Rectangle1();
        private var obj1:Rectangle1 = new Rectangle1();
        private var obj2:Rectangle1 = new Rectangle1();
        private var obj3:Rectangle1=new Rectangle1();
        public var Obj_Arr:Array = [];
        private var vertical_line:VerticalLine;
        private var horizontal_line:HorizontalClass;

        public function Main() 
        {
            obj.x=20;
            obj.y=100;
            addChild(obj);
            obj1.buttonMode = true;

            obj.buttonMode=true;
            obj1.x=150;
            obj1.y=100;
            addChild(obj1);

            obj2.buttonMode=true;
            obj2.x=280;
            obj2.y=100;
            addChild(obj2);

            obj3.buttonMode=true;
            obj3.x=430;
            obj3.y=100;
            addChild(obj3);

            vertical_line = new VerticalLine();
            addChild(vertical_line);
            vertical_line.visible = false;

            horizontal_line = new HorizontalClass();
            addChild(horizontal_line);
            horizontal_line.visible = false;

            Obj_Arr.push(obj);
            Obj_Arr.push(obj1);
            Obj_Arr.push(obj2);
            Obj_Arr.push(obj3);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {
                Obj_Arr[i].index = i;
                Obj_Arr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, OnDown);
                Obj_Arr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, OnUp);
            }
        }

        private function OnDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            e.target.startDrag();
            Obj_Arr.splice(e.target.index,1)
            e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMove);
        }

        private function OnMove(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(e.target.x==(Obj_Arr[i].x)) 
                {
                    trace("vertical...");
                    vertical_line.visible = true;
                    vertical_line.x = Obj_Arr[i].x;
                    vertical_line.y = Obj_Arr[i].y;
                    i = Obj_Arr.length;
                }
                else
                {
                    vertical_line.visible =false;
                }               
            }

            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(e.target.y==(Obj_Arr[i].y)) 
                {
                    trace("horizontal...");
                    horizontal_line.visible = true;
                    horizontal_line.x = Obj_Arr[i].x;
                    horizontal_line.y = Obj_Arr[i].y;
                    i = Obj_Arr.length;
                }
                else
                {
                    horizontal_line.visible =false;
                }
            }
        }

        private function OnUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            vertical_line.visible = false;
            horizontal_line.visible = false;
            e.target.stopDrag();
            Obj_Arr.push(e.target);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < Obj_Arr.length; i++)
            {       
                if(e.target.index == (Obj_Arr[i].index)) 
                {
                    Obj_Arr[i].x = e.target.x;                  
                }
                Obj_Arr[i].index = i;
            }
            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMove);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Marty Wallace:i had explained whatever i want in my question.

Comment: @Marty Wallace:i have edited my answer as per your suggestion.